# Is it possible to use mipmaps with dynamic textures in Dirext 11?

Tags: directx, directx11

I was trying create a texture with `D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC` and `MipLevels` equal to 0 (to create all the mip levels).  However, the texture failed to be created.  Is it possible to use mipmaps with dynamic textures?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create the device with `D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG`, you should see the following error:

> D3D11 ERROR: ID3D11Device::CreateTexture2D: A D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC Resource must have MipLevels equal to 1. [ STATE_CREATION ERROR #102: CREATETEXTURE2D_INVALIDMIPLEVELS]

which is pretty self explanatory.

Use `USAGE_DEFAULT` and `UpdateSubresource()`, instead.

This is a decent summary of the options you have:

https://eatplayhate.me/2013/09/29/d3d11-texture-update-costs/